# GHCJS: setTimeout($c, $1);: invalid placeholder, check function type: "$c"

Tags: ffi, ghcjs

I've installed VM as suggested, and now reading [this article](http://weblog.luite.com/wordpress/?p=14). Now I'm at the very beginning and looking at FFI example. I have missing `ffi.jsexe/` folder (within `ghcjs-examples/weblog/ffi`) and tried to compile it by myself. But it fails with following error:

> `setTimeout($c, $1);: invalid placeholder, check function type: "$c"`

Here is quick reminder what we have in `ffi.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE JavaScriptFFI, CPP #-}

module Main where

#ifdef __GHCJS__
foreign import javascript unsafe "document.write($1+'<br/>');" writeNumber :: Int -> IO ()
foreign import javascript safe   "setTimeout($c, $1);"         delay       :: Int -> IO ()
#else
writeNumber = error "writeNumber: only available from JavaScript"
delay = error "delay: only available from JavaScript"
#endif

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (\x -> writeNumber x >> delay 1000) [1..1000]
```

Sorry, I'm new to Haskell and FP at all, so some thing for me is just alike magic for now.
I've replaced `$c` with `null` because it makes sense since `delay` itself have only one argument, thus there will be no code executed. So it compiles, but when I opened it in a browser all numbers are printed instantly.
Also I have a little pre-question. `setTimeout` return some handler (integral value), and takes a callback function and time in ms, right? So why the `delay` have this type signature `Int -> IO ()` instead of, say, `IO () -> Int -> IO Int`?

And the main question is why it rejects to compile? Is this example outdated and something have been changed in `ghcjs` itself?

```
GHC   7.7.2
GHCJS 0.1.0
```

Comment: You could just use `Control.Concurrent.threadDelay` and let GHCJS handle the plumbing for you.

Answer (score 4):

On the current VM, if I write `interruptible` instead `safe` in the foreign import, it works.